# DECODE to CASE Statement

Tags: sql, case, decode

I am having a bit of trouble modifying this DECODE into a CASE Statement.

```
DECODE(DECODE(pa.postCode_pt1 || ' ' || pa.postCode_pt2,'L9 3DF', 'ZZ99 9ZZ', 'CV23 8AP', 'ZZ99 9ZZ', 'WR11 8TZ', 'ZZ99 9ZZ', postCode_pt1 || ' ' || pa.postCode_pt2),'ZZ99 9ZZ','',pa.address_l1)
```

Best I've come up with so far is something that doesn't quite make logical sense.. because it's a DECODE within a DECODE it's confusing me.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CASE WHEN pa.postCode_pt1 + ' ' + pa.postCode_pt2='ZZ99 9ZZ' (
CASE WHEN pa.postCode_pt1 + ' ' + pa.postCode_pt2='L9 3DF' THEN 'ZZ99 9ZZ'
     WHEN pa.postCode_pt1 + ' ' + pa.postCode_pt2='CV23 8AP' THEN 'ZZ99 9ZZ'
     WHEN pa.postCode_pt1 + ' ' + pa.postCode_pt2='WR11 8TZ' THEN 'ZZ99 9ZZ'
     ELSE pa.postCode_pt1 + ' ' + pa.postCode_pt2) THEN '' 
  ELSE pa.address_l1
END AS Address_Line_1
```

Comment: What is wrong with your sql? Can you add sample data or better [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Well in the inital Case Statement it is expecting THEN after the 'ZZ99 9ZZ' line but if I put it there it gives me an error of an expression of a non-boolean type specified in the context where a condition is expected.

I think its got a lot to do with the bracketing, I just don't know how to do a CASE Statement within a CASE Statement.

Comment: Oh, now I see it. I've edited my answer with sample nested case statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but you should get the idea:

```
case when
(case
when pa.postCode_pt1 || ' ' || pa.postCode_pt2 in ('L9 3DF','CV23 8AP','WR11 8TZ') 
then 'ZZ99 9ZZ'
else postCode_pt1 || ' ' || pa.postCode_pt2 end)
= 'ZZ99 9ZZ' then '' else pa.address_l1 end
```

Syntax for nested case statements:

```
case 
    when A=B then 
      (case 
        when C=D then 1
        when E=F then 2
        else 3 
       end)
    when G=H then
      (case 
        when I=J then 4
        when K=L then 5
        else 6
       end)
     else 7
end
```

I think this should work also without brackets, I've added `()` just for better orientation.

The general structure of `CASE` is (`[]` is optional):

```
CASE WHEN condition THEN result [WHEN...][ELSE result] END
```

You can nest `CASE` as many times you want by replacing `condition` or `result` with other `CASE` structure.

Comment: Had to change || to + because I'm working in T-SQL - but other than that seems to be working smoothly and the logic makes sense. Never thought to use 'IN' either.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query.

```
select case when  case when pa.postCode_pt1 + ' ' + pa.postCode_pt2='L9 3DF'then 'ZZ99 ZZ' else 'WR11 8TZ' end = 'ZZ99 9ZZ' then ' ' else pa.address_l1 end  new_value from dual
```

Comment: This one would have probably worked too, I see where you were going with it. Thank you!